# How to filter/search multidimensional array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have a data structure like below:

```
var options = [{
        name: "Option One",
        foo: "bar",
        values: [{
            name: "Value One",
            value: "Value",
            options: [{
                name: "Option Two",
                values: [{
                    name: "Value Two",
                    value: "Value",
                    options: []
                }]
            }]
        }]
    }, {
        name: "Option Three",
        values: [{
            name: "Value Three",
            value: "Value",
            options: []
        }]
    }];
```

I need to flatten it, filter out properties I don't want and keep knowledge of the depth of each object like the below data structure:

```
var flattenedFilteredOptions = [{
        depth: 0,
        name: "Option One",
        values: [{
            name: "Value One",
            value: "Value"
        }]
    }, {
        depth: 1,
        name: "Option Two",
        values: [{
            name: "Value Two",
            value: "Value"
        }]
    }, {
        depth: 0,
        name: "Option Three",
        values: [{
            name: "Value Three",
            value: "Value"
        }]
    }];
```

So basically I only want the properties of name, values, and value in the output. Can someone point me in the right direction to even start something like this or does anyone have a solution?

Comment: One solution would be to write a recursive function.

Comment: Maybe start with [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11922383/218196) ?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all, here is what I did, keep in mind configuring which properties to filter isn't quite in as configurable, the recursion worked:

```
   function flattenOptions(optionsArray, depth, flattenedOptions) {
        depth = depth || 0;
        flattenedOptions = flattenedOptions || [];

        for (var i = 0; i < optionsArray.length; i++) {
            var option = optionsArray[i];
            var nextDepth = depth + 1;
            var flattenedOption = {
                depth: depth,
                name: option.name,
                values: flattenValues(option.values, nextDepth, flattenedOptions)
            };

            flattenedOptions.push(flattenedOption);
        }

        return flattenedOptions;
    }

    function flattenValues(valuesArray, nextDepth, flattenedOptions) {
        var values = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < valuesArray.length; i++) {
            var value = valuesArray[i];

            values.push({
                name: value.name,
                value: value.value
            });
            if (value.options.length > 0) {
                flattenOptions(value.options, nextDepth, flattenedOptions);
            }
        }

        return values;
    }
```